In big band horn parts, should I write double flats (sharps) or the enharmonic equivalent?
Is it customary to use double accidentals in big band scores?  I know most classical player would prefer them but I'm not sure about the big band tradition.  

Thanks to everyone for the replies!  Is there a book or an online course that deals with these nuances, something like "Notating for the big band" ("Big band notation for dummies"?! :) )

Book recommendations are off topic for this site but pretty much any book about arranging will likely take the “correct” approach to enharmonic spelling. Basically it boils down to: This is the correct way vs This is the way some people do it in real life ;)

I'm amused how three answers with a similar number of votes each, contradict each other: "in general, spell correctly (use double flats)", "in general, use enharmonic equivalent" and "in short, there is no standard".

Which I guess only reinforces the "there is no standard" point.  It would be nice to gather the answer from some first-hand sources like a stack of Count Basie or Woody Herman arrangements.  Maybe they are out for sale somewhere but this would be a project way out of my limits for now.

Short answer: in big band writing there is not as strict a standard for this kind of thing as in classical music so depending on the arranger, you are likely to encounter either. Example 1 despite the double flat is cleaner looking and also correct, Bbb is the b9 of Ab7b9.
Correct enharmonic spelling is taught to people who learn jazz harmony, theory and arranging so when writing an arrangement and a score, it’s important to use correct enharmonic spellings. It makes a score so much easier to read and analyze, especially for someone who did not actually write it.
When writing horn parts there are sometimes exceptions to this. Horn players are not looking at chord changes and analyzing their parts against the harmony, they are trying to sight read their parts as accurately as possible. For that reason, it is more important to make horn parts as easy to read as possible, even if it means bending the enharmonic rules. For example, an ascending passage with chromatic notes is easier to read with sharps than flats and vice versa for a descending line. Other ways to make parts easier to read are trying to avoid several consecutive notes with accidentals and taking advantage of the accidentals in a key signature for simplicity, for example, if there is an Ab7 in the key of G, the b7 can be written as an F# with no accidental as an option if it makes it easier to read and see the shape of the line.

In general, enharmonic equivalents are preferred in jazz horn charts. The exception might be in, say, a chromatic scale, where the double-accidental can help reinforce the direction of the scale, or possibly in the situation where the key is changing (say, a leading tone), to help make clear the change.

In general, you should spell things correctly, even if this means a double accidental. Anyone telling you that a double flat is significantly harder to read than the enharmonic equivalent is a poor reader. You can misspell something if there's a compelling reason, but these situations are rare.
However, one caveat is that minor ninths are commonly misspelled as augmented octaves. I'm not sure why, but I see it all the time.
In this case, the double flat is greatly preferred. It makes the line clearer, and modifying the same note twice (especially in a row) is to be avoided. As a melodic line, the B-double-flat is clearly read as "whatever is the next note chromatically", so the player will press the right keys without even really having to resolve that B-double-flat is enharmonic to A.

I've found the opposite with minor ninths, albeit on keyboards. I disagree that double accidentals are as easy to read, even though they may be 'correct'. The object initially is to make reading as easy as possible, and even for horns, with one staff to follow, A nat is easier to read (and less messy) than Bbb.

There is a tradition in Big Band parts of misspelling 'difficult' notes to make them 'easier'.   This extends beyond double sharps/flats to even discourage Cb, B# etc.
Today's musicians probably don't only play one style of music, and many must find this tradition as irritating as I do.  But it exists.

What I find irritating is, say, in key E, to come across Abm chord instead of the correct G#m.

@Tim, to me those cases seem to be about not knowing key signatures. A little different that the enharmonic/double accidental question.

@Laurence, I don't understand what you mean. If the key is E, there isn't any reason to be thinking of Abm. Not in the sense of using G#m to avoid the Cb in Abm. Basic key signature knowledge provides the G#m. Tim's example is about enharmonics making things more difficult. The OP's question is about using enharmonics to potentially make things easier.

@MichaelCurtis No, I don't know what I meant either!   Comment deleted.
